# How to call function from method inside class

Tags: javascript, html

I have this piece of code:

```js
class TestComponent {
  GenerateView() {
    var btntest = document.getElementById('btntest');
    btntest.onclick = function() {
      // this.test();  //this doesn't work
      alert("ok"); //this works

    }
  }
  test() {
    alert("ok");
  }

}
var d = new TestComponent();
d.GenerateView();
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <button id="btntest">test</button>
</div>
```

Why I can't use `test` `function` in `onclick` event for `btntest`? I have an error

> `this.test` is not a function

When I didn't wrap in `function`, It worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: `btntest.addEventListener("click", (evt) => { evt.preventDefault(); console.log(this); })`

Answer (score 1):

The 'this' part of this.test refers to the btntest element and not your class.

A simple fix for this is make reference variable for your class in your generateView function.

```
GenerateView()
    {
        var THIS = this;
        var btntest = document.getElementById('btntest');
        btntest.onclick = function() {
            THIS.test();
        }
    }
```